# repeated code snippets in R examples for package development

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

So I am developing an R package, and I notice that I keep having the same code snippet repeated in several function examples.

It goes: setup some variables, normalize the data included in the package, show example how to run function.

I am wondering if there is anyway to macro/load in examples? Or define some examples code structure that one can repeat in several functions, or alternatively load in examples from other functions (in my case, the data normalization is a function that is ran before a lot of other functions).

I would really like to avoid copy-paste examples in case lower level functions (again, e.g., normalization) changes, it would be nice if that flows into other functions examples.
I tried searching on stack and google, but I could not find anything on this. Any link or answer is very appreciated.

See the following MWE where we have a common part setting up variables `x` and `y` which could be in their own snippet.

#### MWE:

```
#' Add two variables together
#'
#' This function adds the values of x and y.
#'
#' @param x Numeric value for one of the variables
#' @param y Numeric value of the other variable
#'
#' @name add
#' @return A numeric value of the sum of x and y
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Common part
#' x <- 1
#' y <- 2
#' # Unique part compared to product
#' z <- add(x, y)
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}

#' Multiply two variables together
#'
#' This function takes the product of x and y
#' @inheritParams add
#'
#' @return A numeric value of the product of x and y
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Common part
#' x <- 1
#' y <- 2
#' # Unique part
#' product(x, y)
product <- function(x, y) {
  x * y
}

#' Calculates the mean of the summed variable x
#'
#' @param x Sum of variables to calculate the mean from
#' @param n Number of variables that were summed
#'
#' @return A numerical value for the mean of x
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Common
#' x <- 1
#' y <- 2
#' z <- add(x, y)
#' # Unique
#' n <- 2
#' mean2(z, n)
mean2 <- function(x, n) {
  x*n^-1
}
```

In the MWE we would like one snippet for setting up parameters, then one unique for prod and add, and for mean2 the entire part of add plus a unique part.

Here is a pseudo-code ish take on it:

````
# cannot make ``` so using two `` instead i.e, `` = ```
``{r, commmon_all}
x <- 1
y <- 2
``
# Next part
``{r, add_part} 
run(common_part)
z <- add(x,y)
``
# For manual of add:
#` @examples
#` run(add_part)

# For manual of prod:
#` @examples
#` run(common_part)
#` product(x,y)

# Then for the examples mean2:
#` @examples
#` run(add_part)
#` n <- 2
#` mean2(z, n)
````

where `run(x)` should run and print code

Comment: Maybe you could include a sample data set that is already normalized so it's the more standard example workflow of 1. define variables 2. run function

Comment: Yeah I probably could but the data is already quite large, and I would still need to include the raw data to exemplify the normalization (and e.g., a function that plots comparison between raw and normalized data). I really though there would be something like, @include_example f. (where f is some function ore pre-defined snippet of code). I also have more dependencies after that and it would be nice to have something a bit streamlined. I guess that doesn't exist at this point =/

Comment: You could also use Rmd child documents and put them in `man/rmd/` then render the documents as `child` in several function documentations with `{r, child = "man/rmd/your_document.Rmd"}`.

Comment: Obviously I don't know your use case at all, but I would think that at least some of the time you could run an example on small data. Maybe the normalization can be demonstrated on sample data set, and then you don't include the big raw data. Or maybe some of your post-normalization steps can be demonstrated on a smaller, pre-normalized example. In many cases, examples with smaller data are clearer.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Yeah, I think this is something towards what I am looking for. But this will actually execute the code or just paste it? I've made a simple MWE with a common and unique part. I also am not quite sure how you get the rendering to work, could you post an answer for the MWE?

Comment: @GregorThomas Yeah I agree, but I am also trying to avoid copy-paste code in several documentations. It is not the running time I am overly concerned with, but the robustness of the documentation. I'd prefer that steps f_1 -> f_2 (for two functions, f_1 and f_2 ran sequentially) have the same code to run as steps f_1 -> f_3 (where the f_1 part would look the same for the documentation of f_2 and f_3).